# Implementing UITableView with three "columns" in MapView [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, mapbox

i'm trying to implement the following design with MapBox and a TableView.

[image: Screenshot of the desing]

I've been thinking about it and I wanted to use a UITableView for the results, but as far as I know, it's only possible to have data and detail on the left & right side. Is there an alternative to UITableView ?

If not, i'm also facing the problem that my "root"-View is a `MapView` (from `MapBox`) and that I can't use the `MapViewController` as `UITableViewController` nor as `UITableViewDelegate`/`UITableViewDataSource`. Is it possible to Embed the `MapView` in another View ?

If you need any more information, just let me know. And thank you in advance.

Comment: You can have data wherever you want in a table view cell, you'll just have to implement your own custom `UITableViewCell`

Comment: `UITableViewController` is just a convenience class - all you need to do is put an outlet to a `UITableView`  in your MapController, and implement the `UITableViewDataSource` & `UITableViewDelegate` routines in it. As to the columns on the table, you need to implement your own subclass of `UITableViewCell`. Ray Wenderlich does a good series of tutorials on this.

Comment: @Grimxn I've yet only seen the implementation as ´UITableViewController´ or in the same file as ´Delegate´ & ´DataSource´ - do you have an example implementation of the routine ? That would be awesome ...

Comment: OK, I've sketched an answer...

Answer (score 0):

> but as far as I know, it's only possible to have data and detail on the left & right side. Is there an alternative

You know wrong. You can include any interface you want in a table view cell. Just make this a custom cell and design it as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a `UIViewController` in your storyboard or xib called `ViewController` which has both a `UITableView` and an `MKMapView` (or whatever you are using) correctly connected to the two outlets in the code below:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Now tell the system that we are going to reference our
        // hand-made table cell from a xib called "MyCell"
        self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        // These next you can do here, or in IB...
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK: - TableViewDataSource
    // ANY ViewController can do this, if we register the class as conforming
    // to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Get a reference to an instance of our very own UITableViewCell subclass,
        // Which we registered in `viewDidLoad`
        let c = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell

        // Whatever controls/outlets we have put in our cell subclass,
        // we need to populate with data now... (I just did a label)
        c.cellNumber?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        return c
    }
    //MARK: - TableViewDelegate
    //... implement whatever funcs you need ...

    //MARK: - MKMapViewDelegate
    //... implement whatever funcs you need ...

}
```

You then need to create the following code, AND a stand-alone xib (called in this case "MyCell.xib"). The xib should contain all of the controls you want in your table cell. In my example it has only one control, the `UILabel` referenced as `cellNumber`.

To make the xib, choose "File->New File->User Interface->Empty" from the Xcode menu, then drop a `UITableViewCell` into the xib from the palette. Make sure you change the class of the cell from `UITableViewCell` to `MyCell`. Add whatever controls (and constraints between them) that you need. Obviously, connect all of your controls to relevant `@IBOutlets` in this class.

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    // Create `@IBOutlet weak var ...` for all of the controls in your cell here
    @IBOutlet weak var cellNumber: UILabel!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.configureCell()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.configureCell()
    }

    func configureCell() {
        // Your stuff to load up the IBOutlet controls of your cell with defaults.
        // You will be able to override these when the instantiated cell is passed to
        // `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` 
        // in the `UITableViewDataSource`
    }
}
```