# My TableView datasource functions aren't being called and I don't know why

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, function, uitableview

So I have a UITableView, the kind you drag into a view controller, not a tableviewController.  I set the delegate property to self in the viewDidLoad:

```
    searchTableView.delegate = self
    searchTableView.isHidden = true
    searchTableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

I added a prototype cell to it in storyboard with the identifier "SearchResultCell".  Here's my tableview data source functions:

```
extension MapViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    searchCompleter.queryFragment = searchBar.searchTextField.text!
    let completionResults = searchCompleter.results
    return completionResults.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    searchCompleter.queryFragment = searchBar.searchTextField.text!
    let completionResults = searchCompleter.results
    print(completionResults)

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SearchResultCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = completionResults[indexPath.row].subtitle

    return cell
}

}
```

Literally none of the code in these functions is being called.  (Don't worry, the isHidden and isUserInteractionEnabled functions get switched before I called the table view functions, so that's not the problem)I think I'm somehow not connecting these functions to my specific UITableView, but I don't know what else to do aside from set the delegate to self which I've already done.  Any suggestions as to how I can get these to be called are much appreciated!

Here is a picture of my view controller so you can see if the lack of constraints or positioning are an issue:

[image]

Comment: add also `searchTableView.dataSource = self`

Comment: just added it in but my code still isn't called

Comment: They must be marked as @objc.

Comment: I just marked the functions with @objc and it still isn't working

Answer (score 0):

also You need to add

```
searchTableView.dataSource = self
```

Comment: Just added that in but it's still not being called  :(

Comment: It's weird bc that would make perfect sense as to why it's not called yet it still isn't called for some  reason

Answer (score 0):

You can also set both connections in the storyboard

[image: dataSource]

but then, I think you have another problem - which is that I don't think you can have a UITableView embedded in a MapViewController - here's a discussion about someone else with the same issue [Implementing UITable in MapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42539853/implementing-uitableview-with-three-columns-in-mapview-swift)

I think your solution will be to use a UIViewController which contains both a Map and a Table - you can make it look identical to what you already have.

Comment: Thank you for the update! I will read the link, but I am afraid that I just NAMED is mapViewController.  It is actually what you are suggesting already,  a view controller with a mapview and a tableview, which is making it look like I am running out of solutions here ha.  If you have any other ideas again it is appreciated

Comment: @derek they are might not get called because of the tableview size issues, is it properly positioned on the screen?

Comment: @VitaliiShvetsov actually that has been an issue so maybe that's what's causing it.  It's on the screen, but whenI run the simulator it get pushed down a little and into the middle of the screen.   How can I make sure it's properly positioned?

Comment: @derek if it's pushed down, I guess the constraints are misbehaving (maybe you forgot to add `translatesAutoResizingMasksIntoConstraints`, show how you position it

Comment: I haven't added that, is that  a property of tableview or something else? Here Ill show how it's positioned: EDIT wait how do I post a picture here?

Comment: add it to the main post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220499/discussion-between-vitalii-shvetsov-and-derek).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `completionResults.count` not equal 0.

Comment: Its not because when I put the same code in my searchBar textDidChange function and print the completionResults I get tons of data returned.  The data source functions just aren't being called for some  reason.  thanks